# Does $\sum_{k =1}^n \Big(1 - \frac{1}{\lambda_n \mu_k} \Big)_+$ converge when $\mu_k \to 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, roots, nonlinear-system, fixed-points

Let $\{\mu_k\}$ be a positive, decreasing sequence, such that $\mu_k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$.

For notion,  $x _+ = \max\{0, x\}$ denotes the positive part.

$\underline{\text{Series:}}$ $\quad$ We are going to define two series based on a sequence of numbers $\{\lambda_n\}$ and $\lambda$.
The series are
$$
S_n = \sum_{k =1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_n} \Big(\lambda_n - \frac{1}{ \mu_k} \Big)_+, 
\quad \mbox{and} \quad 
S = \sum_{k =1}^\infty \frac{1}{\lambda} \Big(\lambda - \frac{1}{\mu_k} \Big)_+. 
$$

$\underline{\text{Choice of $\lambda_n, \lambda:$}}\quad$ The scalars $\lambda_n$ and $\lambda$ solve the following equations:
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{\mu_k}\Big(\lambda_n - \frac{1}{ \mu_k} \Big)_+ = 1, 
\quad \mbox{and} \quad 
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty  \frac{1}{\mu_k}\Big(\lambda - \frac{1}{ \mu_k} \Big)_+ = 1.
$$

**Question:**  Is it true that $S_n \to S$ as $n \to \infty$? The main difficulty is that the terms of the series $S_n$ depend on $\lambda_n$ rather than $\lambda$.

Comment: For $n = 1$ the first equation is problematic because $x(1-x) < 1$ for real $x$, so for which $n$ is that supposed to hold?

Comment: @user23571113 Thanks. You caught a typo in my original problem statement. It looks better now, no? In the case $n = 1$, we are just asking $(\lambda - \mu^{-1})_+ = \mu$, it will work to take $\lambda = \mu + \mu^{-1}$ in this case.

Comment: It seems like given the definitions of the scalars one has to have $\lambda=\lambda_n$ for some $n$: since $\mu_k\to 0$ then $\dfrac1{\mu_k}\to+\infty$ and thus any solution $\lambda$ to the latter equation must have $\lambda\lt\dfrac1{\mu_\kappa}$ for some $\kappa$; but then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac1{\mu_k}(\lambda-\dfrac1{\mu_k})_+ = \sum_{k=1}^\kappa\dfrac1{\mu_k}(\lambda-\dfrac1{\mu_k})_+$ and therefore $\lambda$ satisfies the equation for $\lambda_\kappa$ (and all $\lambda_n$ for $n\gt\kappa$).

Comment: You're right. Check my answer and see if you agree.

Answer (score 1):

Following a suggestion of Steven Stadnicki.

$\mu_k$ are decreasing and so $1/\mu_k$ are increasing to $+\infty$.

Consequently, there exists $\kappa$ for which $\lambda < 1/\mu_\kappa$,
and thus $(\lambda - 1/\mu_k)_+ = 0$ for all $k \geq \kappa$.

Consequently,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu_k^{-1} (\lambda - \mu_k^{-1})_+ = 
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \mu_k^{-1}(\lambda - \mu_k^{-1})_+ 
$$
for all $n \geq \kappa - 1$.

This implies $\lambda = \lambda_n$ for all $n \geq \kappa - 1$.

Moreover, for $n \geq \kappa - 1$, it can be verified that
$$
S = S_n = \lambda^{-1} \sum_{k < \kappa} (\lambda - \mu_k^{-1}). 
$$

Comment: Consider the function $f_n(t) := \sum_{k \leq n} \mu_k^{-1} (t - \mu_{k}^{-1})_+$. Without loss, we can regard this as a function $f_n \colon [\mu_1^{-1}, \infty) \to [0, +\infty)$. Isn't the function $f_n$ strictly increasing on this interval? I don't see how there can be more than one solution to $f_n(\lambda) = 1$.

Comment: You're right, I was missing a couple of positive parts in my calculation.